# Training and testing accuracy avoided overfitting and have 98% validation accuracy but classification report is always 0.01%?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I have done fruit detection image classification problem using CNN i have done all the things upto training and fitting the model and my accuracy and validation accuracy are almost 100% but when i try to print classification report and confusion matrix from my model it always shows precision, recall and final accuracy is always 0.01% and confusion matrix is also bizzare. Why is this happenning please help me. Code is available at code section. Thank you.

[This is my code for fruit classification](https://github.com/ganeshkuikel/fruit_classsification/blob/master/Fruits%20Classification.ipynb)

Comment: add shuffle=False and try

Comment: Thank you very much venkata krishnan it worked finally. Can you please tell me what does this shuffle.

Comment: i will post it as an answer, so that it helps future users.  do accept the answer, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You test data is being shuffled, and that's why the classification report gives lower accuracy.
Use

```
shuffle=False
```

for the test set while predicting, so that, you maintain the order of the prediction, in turn comparing it with the correct ground truth value.